# Delete hiberfil.sys and pagefile.sys

Tags: windows

I assume it is save to delete hiberfil.sys and pagefile.sys while Windows is NOT running and they will simply be created again the next time Windows starts. Is this correct?

I want to create a Image of the partition and minimize the image size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hiberfil.sys` is used for hibernating windows (it needs a place to store RAM contents). `pagefile.sys` is used for paging mechanism.

Both can be deleted (though windows will prevent it, you need to do it while windows are not run). But it is better to change the method of an image creation to skip those files or something like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is recreated, not necessarily when windows starts, but when hibernation is turned on again manually.

There are various ways to do this and to prevent it from coming back

https://superuser.com/questions/141033/why-does-hiberfil-sys-come-back-from-the-dead-on-windows-7